# How would I install Budgie in 16.04 without using a PPA?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, budgie

I'm planning on changing desktop environments before the next LTS is released and Unity support is ended. I've looked around the Internet for a while and I either got how to install other desktop environments or posts talking about older versions and using PPA's which I don't think it would need since Budgie is an official flavor now. I've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install budgie
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-budgie-desktop
```

Comment: *"an official flavor now"* - yes, but not in 16.04 AFAIK. See for example the timeline at [Ubuntu Budgie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Budgie)

Comment: No, it is officially supported for the 16.04LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official Ubuntu Budgie website](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads):

> We offer two stable releases - 17.10.1, and 16.04.3
>
> 18.04 is the next LTS and is currently in development - do not use this on production machines.
>   17.10.1 is the current stable release and follows Ubuntu support cadence - Oct 2017 to Jul 2018.
>   16.04.3 is community supported - it is supported until upstream ends support (no current plans) and thereafter, as long as budgie-remix
>   users wish to maintain its support.

https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads

Comment: I have 17. 10  installed. I prefer to install the actual version rather than add it to an existing system.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to go through the hassle of reinstalling Ubuntu and reconfiguring all of my settings. I know there are ways to install multiple DE's on Ubuntu. What I am asking for is the name in the repository.